# selectionChanged event not working in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

Here is my code, in local when i select value from dropdown list selectionChanged event is fired, but when i put this code in server selectionChanged event not firing. please help me to is there any alternative for this, i found this soution from [this URL](https://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LBz6d/)

```
**HTML Code**

    <select data-bind="options: choices, value: selectedChoice"></select>    
    <select data-bind="event: { change: selectionChanged }">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>

**JS Code:**

    var viewModel = {
        choices: ["one", "two", "three"],
        selectedChoice: ko.observable("two") ,
        selectionChanged: function(event) {
             alert("the other selection changed");  
        } 
    };

    viewModel.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       alert("the new value is " + newValue); 
    });


    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your jsfiddle url being secured and the used scripts where not.

If you go to: [http](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LBz6d/) instead of [https](https://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LBz6d/) it should work

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/rniemeyer/LBz6d/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: but i am running this code in my server http://dev-sc8.corsair.com/en-us/memoryfinder it is not working on my server

Comment: The given code should work, so the problem lies somewhere else. Could you show your full js and html files

Comment: here is my files https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=143242B617BA6BE2!8464&authkey=!ALfhswMBsY8wTR8&ithint=folder%2caspx

Comment: What are your errors? Also try removing all the scripts that you don't use from your html. It's total chaos

Comment: Also, i've made a working client side without the ajax request: http://pastebin.com/d7rjWdg6

Comment: if i remove most of the scripts and replace the server call with

     var manufacturer = [{mid:"one",mname:"one"},{ mid:"two",mname:"two"}, {mid: "three",mname:"three"}];
   self.manufacturerList(manufacturer);

it works